# Filter conditions in rest api query SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest

The below REST-URL I used to get the data from lists using filter isn't working. Any ideas?

```
query.RestQuery = "getbytitle('RFA')/Items?$select=ESI_ProjectSeqNoLookupId&$filter=ESI_ProjectSeqNoLookup eq '136616'";
```

Comment: always useful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_List

Comment: what's the error? Are you filtering in a lookup column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you `ESI_ProjectSeqNoLookupId` is lookup column. If it is true, then your approach is not correct.

## Correct Approach

Let's say, lookup column name is `ESI_ProjectSeqNoLookup`. Now the query should look like

```
query.RestQuery = "getbytitle('RFA')/Items?$select=ESI_ProjectSeqNoLookup/Id&$expand=ESI_ProjectSeqNoLookup&$filter=ESI_ProjectSeqNoLookup/Id eq '136616'";
```

- At first, you need to $expand `ESI_ProjectSeqNoLookup`
- Then $select desired columns from lookup list like
  `$select=ESI_ProjectSeqNoLookup/Id, ESI_ProjectSeqNoLookup/Title`
- Then $filter based on any selected column like
  `$filter=ESI_ProjectSeqNoLookup/Id eq '136616'`

For more detail, have a look on my article.

[CRUD Operation to List Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)